# How to show related foreign-key data in Kendo grid column

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid, which is controlled by an angular controller:

```
<div>
    <kendo-grid options="mainGridOptions" k-data-source="gridData">
    </kendo-grid>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**
The data is loading, but the grid isn't rendered. (I also had a term-mismatch and treated sectors as status.

```
"use strict";
angular.module("tenderApp")
.controller("tenderCtrl", ["$scope", "adalAuthenticationService", "tenderSvc", "$q", function ($scope, adalService, tenderSvc, $q) {
    $scope.mainGridOptions = null;
    $scope.gridSource = null;
    $scope.statusData = null;

    function loadStatusData() {
        return tenderSvc.getSector()
            .then(function(sector) {
                $scope.sectorData = sector.data.map(function (obj) {
                    return {
                        text: obj.bezeichnung,
                        value: obj.id
                    };
                });
                return $scope.sectorData;
            });
    }

    function loadGridSource(result) {
        return tenderSvc.getItems()
            .then(function (res) {
                $scope.gridSource = res.data;
                return res.data;
            });
    }

    loadStatusData()
        .then(loadGridSource)
        .then(function (res) {
            //both properties are available at this point
            console.log($scope.gridSource);
            console.log($scope.sectorData);
            $scope.gridData = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                transport: {
                    read: function (e) {
                        e.success($scope.gridSource);
                    },
                    //...
                },
                //...
            });
            $scope.mainGridOptions = {
                toolbar: ["excel"],
                dataSource: $scope.gridData,
                columns: [
                    { field: "sektor", title: "Sektor", values: $scope.sectorData },
                    { command: ["edit"], title: "Aktionen", width: "120px" }
                ]
            };

        });
}]);
```

The problem is, the last call, which should populate the grid, does not work properly. The `console.log` calls show that the data is loaded, but the grid does not show up.

Answer (score 1):

Nice one, now I learn how to do chaining from you. As for your problem, we don't need to use `transport/read`. Instead, we can load the data separately and set it to the grid `dataSource` like this. Note that, please don't put `k-data-source="gridData"` in your grid html attribute since you already have grid options.

HTML:

```
    <div><kendo-grid options="mainGridOptions" k-data-source="gridData">
    </kendo-grid></div>
```

JS:

```
"use strict";
angular.module("tenderApp")
.controller("tenderCtrl", ["$scope", "adalAuthenticationService", "tenderSvc", "$q", function ($scope, adalService, tenderSvc, $q) {
    $scope.mainGridOptions = null;
    $scope.gridSource = null;
    $scope.statusData = null;

    $scope.mainGridOptions = {
        dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource(),
        toolbar: ["excel"],
        columns: [
            { field: "sektor", title: "Sektor", values: $scope.sectorData },
            { command: ["edit"], title: "Aktionen", width: "120px" }
        ]
    };

    function loadStatusData() {
        return tenderSvc.getSector()
            .then(function(sector) {
                $scope.sectorData = sector.data.map(function (obj) {
                    return {
                        text: obj.bezeichnung,
                        value: obj.id
                    };
                });
                return $scope.sectorData;
            });
    }

    function loadGridSource(result) {
        return tenderSvc.getItems()
            .then(function (res) {
                $scope.gridSource = res.data;
                return res.data;
            });
    }

    loadStatusData()
        .then(loadGridSource)
        .then(function (res) {
            $scope.mainGridOptions.dataSource.data($scope.gridSource);
        });
}]);
```

Comment: Your post helped me understand, what went wrong in retrieving the data. My factory already returns a promise. I'll update my question shortly, since the promise issue seems to be resolved, but the grid still doesn't load.